# Matlab efficiency - vectorization

Tags: matlab, vectorization, performance

I have this Matlab code that runs, but i want to make it faster by removing the for loops and essentially do the same calculations using only matrices (my dataset is very large so i need this kind of optimizations):

```
Matrices dimensions: x(N,D), m(K,D), p(K), fL(N,K), maxf(N), maxfL(N), z(N,K).
Also p, maxf, maxfL are row vectors
```

Code1:

```
f = zeros(N,K);
maxf = zeros(1,N);

for n=1:N
   for k=1:K
      % here i had a loop for d dimension but made it more efficient like this:
      f2 = x(n,:) * log(m(k,:))' + (1 - x(n,:)) * log(1 - m(k,:))';
      f(n,k) = log(p(k)) + f2;
   end
   maxf(n) = max(f(n,:));
   f(n,:) = f(n,:) - maxf(n);
end
```

Code2:

```
for k=1:K
  sum2 = sum(z(:,k)); 
  p(k)= sum2/N;
  for d=1:D
     % here i had a n loop for sum1 and made it like this:
     sum1 = z(:,k)' * x(:,d); 
     m(k,d) = sum1/sum2;
  end
end
```

Code3:

```
L_new = 0;
for n=1:N
  suma = sum(fL(n,:));
  L_new = L_new + maxfL(n) + log(suma);
end
```

I will now summarize some average execution times (results are in seconds) from using the below provided answers in my workload (N = 1000, K = 2, D = 784):

```
CodeNumber                      Execution Time
    1           3.98(for_loops), 1.01(Divakar), 0.5(Nishant)
    2           0.2(for_loops), 0.40-0.42(Divakar-2 approaches), 0.13(Nishant)
    3           0.03(for_loops), 0.0026(Divakar), 0.0024(Nishant)
```

Thanks for the answers!!

Comment: Since these are three unrelated codes, I think it would be better to split this into three separate questions.

Comment: They are part of the same code and they are small blocks of it. Someone can provide an answer to one, two or all three of them. I don't believe that splitting them would be beneficial!

Comment: On `Stackoverflow` we don't do partial answers. Still to get on with it, what are the dimensions for `z`, `maxfL`?

Comment: I added the dimensions in the question above!

Comment: In `code2`, would it be `for d=1:K` rather?

Comment: No! it is d=1:D for sure

Comment: And `x(N,K)`  and `z(N,K)` for sure? If so, could you make sure your code runs fine by running it again?

Comment: in code in in the line `f2 = x(n,:) * log(m(k,:))'` , `x(n,:)` is `1 x K `while `log(m(k,:))'` is `D x 1` . So is `D == K`.

Comment: You are absolute right! the dimensions don't match because of a typo! It actually x(N,D) and not x(N,K)! i changed it above!

Comment: Are `maxfL,maxf` column vectors or row vectors ?

Comment: maxFL, maxf are row vectors (since i initialize them with something like zeros(1,N))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code 1:

```
f2 = x*log(m)' + (1-x)*(log(1-m))' ;
f = f2 + ones(N,1)*log(p);
maxf = max(f');
f = f - maxf'*ones(1,K);
```

For code 2:

```
sum2 = sum(z);
sum1 = z'*x;
temp = sum2'*ones(1,D);
m = sum1./temp;
p  = sum2/N;
```

For code 3:

```
L_new = sum(log(sum(fL'))) + sum(maxfL');
```

Comment: I don't think code3 is correct! i re-runed my code and while time was reduced from ~0.001 to ~0.00001 secs, the output value for L_new was different from before!

Comment: And i think the code1 you mention it is actually code2, correct?

Comment: yes you are correct ,check it ,tell me if there is an error, I am looking into code 3 now

Comment: For code2 at: m = sum1./sum2; i get: ??? Error using ==> rdivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: maxFL is a row vector, i will added it also above!

Comment: Now I have cross checked, I believe code 2 and code 3 are correct

Comment: Code2 is correct! Time: from ~0.009 to 0.005~ secs. Also change the d to D in ones(1,d)!

Comment: nishantsny since p is a row vector, we want: p  = sum2/N, in code2, correct?

Comment: nishantsny will you give me also an answer for code1?

Comment: I got help up in some work , code for question 1 will be up shortly

Comment: Thanks (code1 is what is most time-consuming!)! I also did some benchmarking for all the answers and i am going to present them in a nicely fansion as an answer later!

Comment: @JohnZobolas check the code for q.1 and tell the difference in running time

Comment: ones(1,k) => change to ones(1,K) and it is the best time! Code3 for_loop = 3.98 sec, yours = 0.5 and Divakar's is 1.01 secs!!!

Comment: In line (code1): maxf = max(f'); matlab says instead of using transpose, consider using different dimension input argument to max. Can this be changed without losing efficiency and/or it is not important?

Comment: @JohnZobolas I am not sure about efficiency but you can get around the warning by using `maxf = max(f,[],2)';`

Comment: @JohnZobolas I think Nishant's answer deserves the acceptance!

Answer (score 1):

Try these -

**Code 1:**

```
tp1 = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,x,permute(log(m),[3 2 1])),2))
tp2 = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,1-x,permute(log(1-m),[3 2 1])),2))
tp3 = tp1 + tp2
f = bsxfun(@plus,tp3,log(p))
f = bsxfun(@minus,f,max(f,[],2))
```

**Code 2:**

```
p = sum(z)./N;
m = bsxfun(@rdivide,squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,x,permute(z,[1 3 2]))))',sum(z)');
```

**Code 2:** [Approach 2] -

```
p = sum(z)./N;
sum2_1 = sum(z);
m = zeros(K,D);
for k=1:K  
  m(k,:) = sum(bsxfun(@times,x,z(:,k)))./sum2_1(k);
end
```

**Code 3:** (Assuming you are getting `maxfL` from somewhere)

```
L_new = sum(maxfL' + log(sum(fL,2)))
```

Comment: @JohnZobolas Great!! Make sure other codes run and check how they perform against your for-loop codes!!

Comment: Code 2 gets wrong result, but also you don't calculate the p(K) vector

Comment: @JohnZobolas Added calculation for `p` in Code 2. Well I did check the  `m` values for Code 2, so could you double check those?

Comment: You code3 is a little faster than nishantsny's! Some average total execution times in my algorithm give: Code3(Divakar)=~0.0024 and Code3(nishantsny)=~0.0026. Awesome!

Comment: @JohnZobolas What about Code 1 and 2?

Comment: I try them now! Please wait!

Comment: Well, Code2 is now correct (i do later on the algorithm calculations that need the p values so without them i got the wrong result before!). As for performance (average many execution times): Code2_for_loops = ~0.2 s, Code2_Divakar = ~0.4 s, and Code2_nishantsny = 0.13 secs!

Comment: @JohnZobolas Just curious what are the typical values of `N`, `K`, `D`?

Comment: N = 1000-5000, K=2 (i want up to go up to 100), D= 784

Comment: @JohnZobolas Could you check out just added **Code 2:** [Approach 2]  for benchmarking?

Comment: your Code1 get this: ??? Error using ==> bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other, at f = bsxfun(@plus,tp3,log(p)');

Comment: @JohnZobolas Fixed, check it out!! The error was because I assumed `p` as column vector before you mentioned that it's a row vector.

Comment: Approach 2 gets: 0.42 secs, in fact it is a little worse!

Comment: @JohnZobolas Added pre-allocation for `m` in Code 2 which might be making it a bit slower.

Comment: That's true! (still 0.42 secs!)

Comment: @JohnZobolas `Code 1` evaluation going on?

Comment: Yeah! For Code3 for_loop = 3.98 sec, yours = 1.01 and nishantsny's is 0.5 secs!!! I belive that using bsxfun make the code faster but not as fast as finding the exact mulitplications that are needed in matrix format...

Comment: @JohnZobolas I think you are talking about Code 1, arent you?

Comment: Yes! It's for Code1! i first check correctness and its Ok and then re-run to get time results. I always compare with the initial for loops that i know for sure they are correct!